# Overfull \vbox caused by tall text in multirow

Tags: tables, multirow

This is my first post here. I am struggling with overcoming problem of overfull \vbox warning. It is caused by three-lined cell of a table while it `\multirow`'s only two one-lined. In fact in my main document using `\\[0.5cm]` works pretty well, but still produces the warning.

In MWE it also has nasty in-table margins.

I would appreciate any help from you. Thank you!

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht]
    \footnotesize
        \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{c | m{1.9cm} | X X | X X | X X | m{1.7cm} }
        blabla & blabla & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{blabla} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{blabla} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{blabla} & blabla \\ \hline
        & & \multicolumn{6}{ c| }{Name} & \multirow{2}{1.7cm}{Some pretty long text} \\ \cline{3-8}
        & & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6  & \\ \hline
        \end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Well, you want three lines of text in a two rows `\multirow`. This is for sure an overfull vertical box. Just increase the width of your cell to `\multirow{2}{1.9cm}{Some pretty long text}` and you ready to go. (same thing for the `m{1.9cm}` above, of course).

Comment: If you don't want to change the column width, in the second and third rows you could add some invisible rules, such as `\rule[1.5ex]{0pt}{2.5ex}`, to increase the vertical space.

Comment: Thanks, adding a rule did the work. Just thought there is some pretty way to increase row height.
LaRiFaRi, I do not have room to increase column width.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on @GonzaloMedina's comment, since the column width is fixed and three lines of text are available (conceptually), a way to make the text fit into the three rows is to insert vertical rules which expand the second and third row. This won't get rid of the overfull boxes, but they will make the table look ok.

I propose two solutions. One without all of the vertical lines stuff and with fancy rules via `booktabs`

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage{tabularx, booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
    \footnotesize
        \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}c m{1.9cm} *{6}{X}   m{1.7cm}@{} }
        \toprule
        blabla & blabla & \multicolumn{2}{c}{blabla} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{blabla} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{blabla} & blabla \\ \midrule
      \rule[1.5ex]{0pt}{2.5ex}  &\rule[1.5ex]{0pt}{2.5ex} & \multicolumn{6}{ c}{Name} & \multirow{2}{1.7cm}{Some pretty long text} \\ 
        & \rule[1.5ex]{0pt}{2.5ex}& 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6  & \\ \bottomrule
        \end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The second adds the rules to the original table, **but looks uglier to me** (since vertical separator do not help readability and too many horizontal rules make the table bulkier)

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht]
    \footnotesize
        \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{c | m{1.9cm} | X X | X X | X X | m{1.7cm} }
        blabla & blabla & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{blabla} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{blabla} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{blabla} & blabla \\ \hline
        &\rule[1.5ex]{0pt}{2.5ex} & \multicolumn{6}{ c| }{Name} & \multirow{2}{1.7cm}{Some pretty long text} \\ \cline{3-8}
        &\rule[1.5ex]{0pt}{2.5ex} & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6  & \\ \hline
        \end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]